# Query reversed when I use "category__not_in"

Tags: query

When I use "category__not_in" it works - but the query is reversed.

```
$args = array (
   'post_type'        => array( 'post' ),
   'post_status'      => array( 'publish' ),
   'category__not_in' => array( 74, 77 ),
   'posts_per_page'   => '6',
   'paged'            => $paged
);
```

Maybe anyone had the same problem before and has a tipp?
("*order*" and "*orderby*" does not help)

EDIT: I misunderstood something, I have to use "post__not_in" instad ;)

Comment: Note that queries like this that say what you don't want are expensive and don't scale

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I wasn't sure about the performance! I do this now with a extra custom post type ;).

Comment: A custom taxonomy would also work ( if you ever write a meta query, you have the same problem )